# I get a blank product page on open cart

Tags: php, opencart

I installed an open cart on my company website and have been using it for quite some while now. But all of a sudden it has stopped working.

The products show a completely blank page
The "add to cart" button doesn't work
I cannot edit or insert new products via the admin

Please guys I have tried everything I know.

I have re-installed and over-written all the files in the open cart, yet the problems still persist. Can someone out there help because I'm under pressure to fix this

Thank you.

Link to my site is http://www.afro-foods.com
Link to a product: 
http://afro-foods.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=25_67&product_id=87

Comment: That means either your script is calling `die()` at some point or meeting a fatal error, but nothing is displayed because its configured to not display errors. If I had to guess its some include you are calling only when the product exists. In either case we would need to see some code to help you.

Comment: If you've recently updated your php version, this may have given an issue I've just come across where mcrypt isn't installed and needs reinstalling